# Passing Variables Through Javascript's location.reload(true)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, refresh, reload

I have a webpage with a really large MySQL query as the result. The query is changed depending on the user, so it will be different for each person. I am trying to provide a method of resorting the query by making the headers into clickable links.

My query results page is written in PHP and HTML for the most part.

For each column header, I have the following:

```
echo "<th id='frame_data_table'>
    <a href='javascript:location.reload(true)'>XBox 360 Command</a>
</th>";
```

On clicking the column header link, the page will reload using the javascript in the a href. This is the most successful way I've been able to get my webpage to reload with all of the query information.

All I need to do now is figure out how to pass another variable upon clicking the header link. I have tried to do syntactical variations of something like

```
echo "<th id='frame_data_table'>
    <a href='javascript:location.reload(true)+?var1=command_column'>XBox 360 Command</a>
</th>";
```

with no success. Once I get the variable to pass, I will just grab it with $_GET[''], no problem.

Any advice? It's worth noting that after extensive googling, I saw a lot of `location.href`. This does not reload my page, and in fact all it really does (in Chrome, anyway) is load a page with just the text url of the page I want.

Is there any way to pass a variable in the url using javascript's location.reload()? Thanks in advance.

-Anthony

**UPDATE: Solution**

I asked a similar question and was able to obtain a solution. See the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28396518/2664815). The solution is fully explained in the bottom of the question.

Comment: If you need to change the url, you are not reloading the page.

Comment: whats the problem with location.href.   window.location.href = "www.yourdomain.com?get=variable"

Comment: i would switch to client side sorting with js

Comment: The problem with using location.href='www.mydomain.com?get=variable" is that when I do that, it does not pass any of the (many) parameters that builds my query that displays on a table in the resulting page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
location.href = location.href + "?var1=command_column"
```

will redirect you to the current URL with the added parameter, i.e. the page will be effectively reloaded.

Comment: I've tried something like that with no luck, but it might be the syntax. I have my javascript in a php echo statement. How would I go about typing that in a PHP echo statement after <a href=...?

Comment: Going to submit as an answer because it was helpful in me understanding how to reload the page. Please see the updated question for a link to the solution in another question I asked.