# Passing variable PHP, Javascript location.reload, and HTML input

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, reload

I have a page that runs a MySQL query off of a button click. The query result displays about 6 or so columns with about 100 rows.

I would like the user to be able to resort the query results based on clicking the column headers. Pretty much sending them to the same page with the same query, just resorted.

So here is what I have so far, all in the same script.

**HTML table (echoed in PHP)**

```
echo "<th id='frame_data_table'><a onClick='innerChange()' href='#'>Command</a></th>";
```

**Javascript function**

```
function innerChange() {
    document.getElementById("innerTest").value = "Changed it.";
    location.reload(true);
}
```

**HTML input tag and php form handling**

```
<?php echo "-->" . $_POST['commandSort'] . "<--"; ?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="innerTest" name="commandSort" value="command" />
</form>
```

When I do this, when the page reloads nothing shows up for `echo $_POST['commandSort']`. Neither the original value nor the changed value is displayed.

Really, all I need is the `$_POST['commandSort']` to grab the value of the changed input box, and then I can implement placing whatever value I want to into my query to order it however I want.

Thanks in advance!

-Anthony

==================================================================

**UPDATE: Solution**

The solution to this (credit goes to one of the users who I selected as the answer for) was by using `document.getElementById['mainForm'].submit()`. Here is what I have.

**HTML Form**

```
<html>
<!--...some html code here...-->
<form method="post" id="mainForm" action="example.com/results.php">
  <!--...more code inside of the form here...-->
  <input type="checkbox" name="command" value="command" id="command"/><p>Command</p>
  <!--...more code inside of the form here...-->
  <input type="hidden" name="hiddenSort" id="hiddenSort" />
  <!--...more code inside of the form here...-->
</form>
<!--...some more html code here...-->
</html>
```

**PHP example.com/results.php Page with Javascript**

```
<?php
/*...more php code here...*/
<if (isset($_POST['command'])) {
  ?><th id="frame_data_table"><a href="javascript:sortFunction('command');">Command</a></th><?php
}
/*...more php code that displays the query result (while(...)) here...*/
?>
```

**Javascript Function**

```
<script>
  function sortFunction(x) {
    var sortVar = x;
    document.getElementById("hiddenSort").value = x;
    document.getElementById("mainForm").submit();
  }
</script>
```

Explanation: After the initial query result is fetched and displayed, if the user clicks on the "command" column link, the `document.getElementById['mainform'].submit()` resubmits the same form as was previously run, while at the same time passing the variable through the javascript function x. The variable dictates how the query will be resorted, as all that really needs to be done is populate a variable with `"ORDER BY " . $_POST['commandSort']` in PHP. Feel free to message me for a further explanation if you are encountering a similar problem.

Thanks for all who responded.

-Anthony

Comment: Wouldn't you have to submit the form instead of just refreshing the page? Give the form an id then instead of location.reload use `document.getElementById("myForm").submit();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST['commandSort']` is null because you don't submit the form, try instead of

`location.reload(true);`

with

`document.forms["form1"].submit();`

renaming

`<form method="post" id="form1">`.

Comment: This brings me a bit closer I guess. What I need is still not working, but to be more specific the original form that allows the user to see the query result in the table is in a different document `index.php`, and the results are in `results.php` with `index.php` included in the results document. Is it possible for me to use your method of document.forms[''].submit() in the results script (where the column links will be) to resubmit the form referencing my original form in index.php?

Comment: I don't understand the scheme of your pages, but if you want to submit for another page you can change action="page where i want to submit". Moreover you can try to change system, doing it with Ajax .

Comment: I was able to accomplish this using `document.getElementById['formName'].submit()`, almost the same thing that you recommended. Full solution will be put in the original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to use JavaScript for this? It can be done with HTML and PHP.

eg.

```
<tr>
<th><a href="myfile.php?sort=blah1">Header Text 1</a></th>
<th><a href="myfile.php?sort=blah2">Header Text 2</a></th>
..
</tr>
```

then in PHP you can retrieve that value with:

```
$sort = $_GET['sort'];
```

Comment: I've tried this way before.

I am not too familiar with reload, refresh, etc... and how it all operates, but when I do it this way, the query does not pass along with the page being reloaded.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to reload the page, wouldn't you just click on the header text which then goes to a page with ?sort=blah and displays the sorted rows, pressing f5 after that should still sort the data because the ?sort=blah is still in the URL. Also this way you wouldn't need any JS like: location.reload etc.

Comment: I don't really know exactly why I would want to reload the page either, or what the exact difference would be between reload or the method that you chose. All I know is that when I've tried your method in the past, the query result does not show up on the page anymore, but when I use `location.reload` then it does. The query is highly customized by the user, allowing the user to select the columns they want, and what data shows up in the query result. I need to keep the query result that user selects, but resort the data. I don't know how to use your method and pass the same results.

Comment: The user selects the query results through check boxes on another part of the page, and what exactly shows up in certain columns. I want to give the user the option to click on the top of one of the columns to resort the data.

Comment: Well you could build the link's query in PHP, containing all the data from $_GET, and stick that in the link (using just html / php).

Answer (score 0):

on click of button you can do:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace( /[\?#].*|$/, "?q=mysort" );
```

and get sort option as `$sort= $_GET['q'];`